# HTML5 application cache update issue (updates from browser cache)

Tags: web-applications, http-headers, html5-appcache

I have been goggling quiet a while now without any luck on this issue, hope someone can help.

The issues concern the application cache, browser cache and proxies when developing an web-app with application cache.

**About the web-app:**

The web-app displays high-resolution images and allows the user to navigate between them. To make the interaction fluent, all the images are pre-loaded using ajax (the loading is semi-intelligent so it will display images when they are loaded and then continue to load the rest in the background). In addition to this, the entire web-app is cached in the application cache (using a manifest file) to make it accessible offline on iPad. Also, this will improve the general performance in other browsers.

**The issue:**

When the manifest file is updated, the browser (tested mainly in Chrome and Firefox on OSX) loads the files from the browsers cache instead of requesting them from the server. Sometimes, the browser cache has expired, and the request will go to the actual server or to a proxy. Oftentimes this results in the web-app not being updated.

We have tried to at a caching control header:

no-cache, must-revalidate 
(no-cache required for getting it to work in Firefox).

This works perfect for browsers that support application cache forcing them to include these two headers in their requests:

- If-None-Match
- If-Modified-Since

when the are requesting new assets from the manifest file. However, in browsers that don't support application cache or browsers that are told not to cache anything through the manifest file no files are cached in the regular browser cache. These browsers will then request the image again when they are displaying it (not using the cached one already downloaded through the ajax call). The server will respond with 304, so the issue is not too bad, but it is not the optimal solution.

**What i would like:**

I would like browsers that caches files in the application cache to include the two headers:

- If-None-Match
- If-Modified-Since

When they see the manifest-file has been updated. For browsers that do not use the application cache I would like it to cache the files as usual not sending multiple requests to the server in the same session.

Is this possible, or is there another solution to the problem?

Thanks for your help.